# Can not figure out a simple 4 box JPanel layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have been trying for hours to get `JPanel` in Java to contain these 4 other panels in this configuration (see picture)

- The blue box should never change size.
- The white box should never change height, can get wider though.
- The dark grey box should never change widths, can get taller though.
- The light grey box can get taller or wider.

Seems pretty simple to me, I did it in C# the other day and it was a breeze. Set the position, the width, height, and whether a certain side was anchored or not, boom done, I was starting to like java more than C until I ran into this.

I've tried countless combinations of `GridBagLayout`, multiple nested `BoxLayout` instances. They all seem to do very strange things, like make each panel a tiny 4 x 4 square, or there is crazy padding around them, or the ones that need to re-size with the window, don't.

Is there some kind of magic combination that can achieve this? Does the `null` layout do anchoring or percent dimensions.

The closest I've gotten is the bottom image with `GridBagLayout`, which looks good when it loads, but does that when you re-size the window.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code that got the above images

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
public MainPanel(){
    this.setBackground(new Color(216,216,216));
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel topTitle = new JPanel();
    topTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 40));
    topTitle.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 40));
    topTitle.setBackground(new Color(174, 216, 249));
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(topTitle,c);

    JPanel mainHeader = new JPanel();
    mainHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1060, 40));
    mainHeader.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1060, 40));
    mainHeader.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(mainHeader,c);

    JPanel sideNav = new JPanel();
    sideNav.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 760));
    sideNav.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 760));
    sideNav.setBackground(new Color(110,110,110));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(sideNav,c);

    JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel();
    dataPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1060, 760));
    dataPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1060, 760));
    dataPanel.setBackground(new Color(216,216,216));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(dataPanel,c);
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: And don't event think on using null layout... You'll regret it if you do so. Also as mentioned by @AndrewThompson post at least one of your codes when you tried solving it, this way it will be easier for us to say what's wrong on your code

Comment: *"And don't event think on using null layout..."* I didn't notice mention of the `null` layout until editing the post. Could not agree more.

Comment: Thanks, code added

Comment: Two points on the code: 1) That is **not** an MCVE / SSCCE. They must include imports and a `main(String[])` method to launch it and show the example! I included an MCVE in my answer. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Ok thank you for the tips for future posts. Are you directing that comment about the bracket outside of the code towards me? I pressed the code button, pasted the code, and that is what this website did to it. Seems like it's out of my control, I just tried to edit it and it just does the same thing so.,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GUI at minimum size

[image: GUI at minimum size]

### GUI stretched wider & taller

[image: GUI stretched wider & taller]

It's all about getting appropriate resize weights & fill values..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FourPanelLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    FourPanelLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        // It appears you don't want space around the panels.
        // If not, commment out or remove this line.
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        
        // create the panels, each with a transparent image to suggest a size
        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        bluePanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getTransparentImage(40, 20))));
        
        JPanel darkGrayPanel = new JPanel();
        darkGrayPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        darkGrayPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getTransparentImage(40, 20))));
        
        JPanel whitePanel = new JPanel();
        whitePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        whitePanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getTransparentImage(40, 20))));

        JPanel grayPanel = new JPanel();
        grayPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        grayPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getTransparentImage(360, 80))));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0f;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0f;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        ui.add(bluePanel, gbc);
        
        gbc.weightx = .5f;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        ui.add(whitePanel, gbc);
        
        gbc.weighty = .5f;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        ui.add(grayPanel, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 0f;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        //gbc.gridy
        ui.add(darkGrayPanel, gbc);
    }
    
    /* We use transparent images to give panels a natural size. */
    private Image getTransparentImage(int w, int h) {
        return new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                FourPanelLayout o = new FourPanelLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way! On mine I just changed had to change the weights and it seems to be working. I also didn't realize (even though its obvious) that the constraints would apply to all the ones below it as well if I didn't reset them, or order them specifically like you did, so my orig. code had that problem too.

Comment: Andrew I'm sorry, but, what you mean by *We use transparent images to give panels a natural size* what's the advantage of using the transparent image over just filling the panel's background?

Comment: @Frakcool The way the GUI is designed, without images to 'fill out' the panels, they will all be 0 x 0 pixels in size. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I see, I was on the phone so I couldn't test it before, I see what you mean now, thank you for clarifying :)

Comment: @Frakcool No problem. I recall earlier you were saying you were posting via phone.

Answer (score 3):

To implement this, I recommended to use [FormLayout](https://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/formlayout/).

**FormLayout** is a powerful, flexible and precise general purpose layout manager. It places components in a grid of columns and rows, allowing specified components to span multiple columns or rows. Not all columns/rows necessarily have the same width/height.

**Note:** It good to use [Windowbuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) in Eclipse or [GUI Form](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/designing-gui-major-steps.html) in Intellij to automatically place and set the components properties.

[image]

Comment: *"it is recommended"* **I** don't recommend using 3rd party layouts when this is easily achievable using core Java layouts. Perhaps you should edit that to *"**I** recommend"*..

Comment: Done as you wish. Thanks

Comment: *"It good to use Windowbuilder"* It is *better* to understand how to layout components by hand! My experience suggests to me that GUI design tools are much more effective then the user actually understands how to use (and combine) layouts. Good call on that first edit. :)

Comment: Looks like a neat alternative, I'm trying to stay with what tools I already have though, I'm learning this for college so would need to know how to do it without it anyways.

Comment: "Easily achievable" With `GridBagLayout` it is neither easy, nor achievable. At least you cannot create a portable solution. `GridBagLayout `uses fixed gaps which are simply not usable on different kinds of screens (these days there are plenty of them). From the built-in Java layouts, only `GroupLayout` can create truly portable UIs. There are actually only three layouts which can be used for modern UI: `MigLayout`, `GroupLayout`, and `FormLayout`; therefore, "It is recommended " has some merit.

Comment: @JanBodnar 1) You seem to have missed my (accepted) answer, which indeed uses `GridBagLayout`. 2) Perhaps you should save your comments on layouts until you appear on the first page [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/layout-manager/topusers). Or to put that a different way, prove it with your well up voted answers  Anything less is just ..hot air. 3) *""It is recommended " has some merit."* Feel free to recommend it, just don't go implying it is a general consensus.

Comment: @AndrewThompson In 2003 (!!!) Karsten Lentzsch, the author of JGoodies, has written a white paper, where he clearly stated the shortcomings of existing layout managers. And still, in 2016, people are here recommending the obsolete `GridBagLayout`. By recommending `GridBagLayout`, you are doing a big disservice to the novice programmers. My comment was not meant to be personal, it is factual. Read that white paper and you will find out why `BoxLayout`, `BorderLayout`, `GridBagLayout` are not acceptable.